# How to call two separate command from one user control in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol

I have user control which contain two buttons 'Add' and 'Delete' which call commands for add data into datagrid. and i use this user control two occasion.

I also have two DataGrid for 'Staff' and 'Department'.

[This is UI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEvOE.png)

So how i attach two different commands to each control buttons.?

[Those are buttons of User Control and attached Commands.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qICes.png)

(Sorry for English.)

Comment: If you want to attach two different commands to one button, you are most likely doing something incorrectly

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could add whatever code you have into the question itself

Comment: What you can do simple way is expose property of your user control which takes parameter ( as entity for which operation needs to be performed e.g. User / Department) and then call respective Service/view model method your control need to have references in this case

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could add an event to your user control; or even a dependency property and simply give it an action

Comment: Not two commands in one buttons but one command for each Use Control button. like if i click top 'Add' button it should add into department datagrid or if down 'Add' it should add into staff datagrid. but without onclick events. #Kajbo

Comment: I don't want to use events. @pm_2

Comment: Expose Commands from ViewModel and then apply Binding to the Buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the question reasonably clear when you look at the picture.
More explanation would allow a precise description of exactly how to do this but here goes.

The DataContext is inherited down the tree of controls.
There are two expanders in the picture.
Let's call whatever goes in the content for these usercontrols. Maybe they are, maybe they're not. It doesn't really matter. Let's call them Departments and Staff Details.
Let's say the Delete button binds DeleteCommand.
If you set the datacontext of Departments to a viewmodel which exposes a DeleteCommand ICommand property then it will bind to that.
Similarly, set the datacontext of Staff Details to another viewmodel which exposes a deletecommand then the button in staff details will bind to the DeleteCommand in the viewmodel for Staff Details.

All you need is two different viewmodels with these different commands in them and make them the datacontext of your expanders.

Comment: I Understand partially, i got the idea after reading your ans. Thanks.!